# How to deal with systemic gaps in timeseries data

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, forecasting, deepar

To be clear this question is not how to input missing data, but how to treat an exchange dataset that will not ever have data on weekends and occasionally on market holidays. I'm working with the DeepAREstimator from gluonTS. The Estimator needs the dataset to be inputted in a uniform manner (i.e. no gaps on nights, weekends, holidays, etc...) I have filled out the dataset using interpolation or forward fill but I was wondering what are other methods or even other models can be used in this situation.